# Can't rename or move folders on network drives in Windows 7 anymore

Tags: windows-7, networking

I can't connect to two network drives via a VPN connection to my workplace's server anymore.

Everything was fine until recently since when I started to receive an error message "The File or Folder does not exist" whenever I try to create a new folder and assign a name to it. The renaming you usually do while you create a folder fails and I am left with a folder titled "New Folder". Also, I can't move folders around on that drive. Sometimes, newly created folders end up in the root directory. Copying files doesn't work properly either, as they often end up in the root directory too instead of the folder they were originally assigned to.

I have no folder or file copying issues on my own drive.

In search of a remedy, I found [this thread on another forum](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/130137-cannot-rename-move-file-folder-vista-fix.html) that discusses the issue. I have already tried step 1 described in there which consists in disabling offline files - no improvement.

I am reluctant proceeding towards step 2 which consists in applying a registry fix. I'm afraid some file from the internet could mess up by system. Plus, it says it's for Windows Vista while I'm running on Windows 7 64-bit.

Any advise please?

Comment: I'm assuming you are part of a domain and you've talked to the admin?

Comment: yes, i have write access to the domain and the admin has no explanation. In fact, files and folders DO get written on the network drive, but not in the right spot.